# Remove duplicate rows from MySQL table (ignore chars and whitespace)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table 'people':

```
id[byte], name [varchar], surname [varchar], size [int]
```

with about 1k rows, most of them are duplicates for example

- Xbyte1X, 'mike', ' anders', 5
- Xbyte2X, 'Mike', 'andERS ', 5

or

- Xbyte1X, '', '', 0;
- Xbyte2X, '', '', 0;

and i would like to delete duplicates, but I have to deal with:
 - trim
 - big / low chars
 - null / empty records

I have to rememeber 'oid' of deleted row, because I have to replace it in other table (it's relational model)
How to make a procedure which can fix my table 'person' and remove duplicates like that?

PS it's just a sample table, real table it's with few columns more and much more data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved similar problem in an ETL process the way bellow: 
**The strategy:**

- Add at least two new columns to people table `IsDuplicate` and
  `NewID` (or create a new table from people table data, and then add
  the new columns).
- Run the procedure to detect the duplicate record, update the records `IsDuplicate` to `true` and fill the `NewId` column to the refereed record `ID`.
- You will end up with records in people table, marked as `IsDuplicate   = true` with NewId of its duplicated row, now you can find these records related data in the other tables and update the relation with `newId` value.
- Now its time to remove the redundant data from people table, it is highly
  recommended to keep a backup of the table.

**Finding the duplicated data:**
Finding duplicated data will be as hard as choosing which record of the duplicate set needs to be removed, this will depends on your application business, a sample can be choosing oldest `id`.
 A formula to get duplicates can be creating a standard name like : `CONCAT(Upper(Trim(Replace(people.name,' ',''))) ,Upper(Trim(Replace(people.surname' ',''))))`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep. There is no one solution, for such steps we need strategy. I make some fix on that and use it (without creating new columns, but it took more memory and time)